# Add a job to SLURM queue with higher priority as previously submitted jobs

Tags: slurm

I want to submit and run a job X to a SLURM queue while already having other jobs YZ waiting in that queue.
Basically, I want to avoid doing `scontrol hold YZ` manually or find an automated way to `scontrol hold YZ` with the submission of X and `scontrol release YZ` as soon as the job X finishes.

Cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is the `scontrol top <jobID>` command, which puts a job on top of other jobs of the same user ID. But it has to be enabled by the system administrator.

To quote the [scontrol man-page](https://slurm.schedmd.com/scontrol.html#OPT_top):

> **top** job_list
>
> Move the specified job IDs to the top of the queue of jobs belonging to the identical user ID, partition name, account, and QOS.
> The job_list argument is a comma separated ordered list of job IDs.
> Any job not matching all of those fields will not be effected. Only
> jobs submitted to a single partition will be effected. This operation
> changes the order of jobs by adjusting job nice values. The net effect
> on that user's throughput will be negligible to slightly negative.
> This operation is disabled by default for non-privileged
> (non-operator, admin, SlurmUser, or root) users. This operation may be
> enabled for non-privileged users by the system administrator by
> including the option "enable_user_top" in the SchedulerParameters
> configuration parameter.